# Como puedo hacer regresion Lineal en python?

Tags: python, anaconda

una consulta. Realicé la regresión lineal en Excel y no me coinciden los datos. ¿Que tengo mal en este código, y como logro importar una ruta para que en una variable me lea todo el .csv y ponerlo a entrenar?

Comment: ¿Quieres generar una red neuronal o inteligencia artifical?

Comment: Pues por el momento ambas , pero empezamos el tema basico de Regresión (solo teoria) y debo averiguar pronóstico para el mes de venta nro. 7. Me dan un dataset pero pues al no saber casi lo ingrese manual pero quisiera aprender a tomar el dataset agregarlo a una variable y realizar el mismo procedimiento de la linea de codigo 12 hasta la 15 pero no eh podido hacer algo.  Agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: Tus datasets los puedes crear con  [Pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), para la parte de analisis numerico te recomiendo que leas estadistica, [regresion lineal con python](https://iartificial.net/regresion-lineal-con-ejemplos-en-python/) con esos puedes empezar

Comment: Gracias. Quiere decir que no hay forma de tomar .csv  de un directorio y importarlo a mi codigo almacenado en una variable y despues disponer de esta variable para realizar el entrenamiento de mi dataset?

Comment: otro problema que tengo es que sigo tutoriales en youtobe y pues me sale el error   File "C:\Users\CARLOS\Sin título0.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pandas as pd...pero ya lo instale nose que mas hacer

Comment: Ok, acabo de responder a tu pregunta de forma abierta para siempre puedas volver a ella y revisar, ahora sobre la pregunta trata de instalarlo te anexo este (link)[https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html] en el cual viene como instalar pandas desde anaconda

Comment: Si te sirvió mi respuesta, ponle palomita. Además conviene que edites el título de tu pregunta a algo así como: "¿Cómo hacer una regresión lineal en python?"

Comment: Aparte del título, no agregues nunca pantallazos para mostrar el código, es muy posible que el voto negativo sea por eso. Las imágenes dificultan la legibilidad (peor aún en pantallas pequeñas de dispositivos móviles), dificultan la reproducción del código y no indizan para futuras búsquedas. Pega código y errores como texto siempre, luego lo seleccionas y pulsas Ctrl + k o el botón {} del editor para formatearlo. Por cierto, bienvenido a [es.so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres hacer una regresión lineal en Python yo te recomendaría usar la librería `sklearn`. Viene con una clase llamada `LinearRegression` con la que es muy fácil hacerlo.

Un ejemplo sería el siguiente:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Tus datos (este es un ejemplo)
metros_cuadrados = np.array([[75, 60, 55, 80, 120, 130, 145, 100]]).T
precios = np.array([[180000, 150000, 135000, 210000, 230000, 250000, 300000, 170000]]).T
```

Una vez tienes los datos, creas el regresor lineal de la siguiente forma y lo entrenas.

```py
# Regresor lineal
modelo = LinearRegression()
# Entrenamos el modelo con los datos existentes
modelo.fit(metros_cuadrados, precios)
```

Y en `modelo` ya tendrías el modelo listo para ser usado. Puedes predecir la salida para una determinada entrada.

```py
valores_a_predecir = np.array([[50, 60, 55, 80, 120, 130, 145, 150]]).T
y_predichos = modelo.predict(valores_a_predecir)
```

El ejemplo ha sido sacado [de este blog](https://cursospython.com/regresion-lineal/). Tiene un par de ejemplos muy interesantes donde se explica también la función coste y el *gradient descent*.

Answer (score 2):

Si vas a usar scikit-learn creo que deberías usar `LinearRegression` en vez de una `svm`.

Aquí está como lo resolví usando NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Y = [7000, 9000, 5000, 11000, 10000, 13000]

model = np.polyfit(x, Y, 1)
predict = np.poly1d(model)

print("7 = {}".format(predict(7)))
```

Esto me arroja una predicción de `13066.6667`

Como adicional, si quieres graficar ésto, es sencillo, justo abajo del programita anterior:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x, predict(x), c='r')
plt.scatter(x, Y)
```

No le quise poner ninguna floritura como títulos o algo similar. El parámetro `c=r` es lo único, para que pinte la línea de regresión en rojo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si quieres usar sckit-learn (para algo tan sencillo usaría NumPy), tendrías que hacer algo así como:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
x = df.x.values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df.y.values.reshape(-1,1)

reg = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
reg.predict([[7]])
```

... e igual, te da el mismo resultado.

Comment: Ese es el resultado 13.066. Muchisimas gracias...el 1 que hace model = np.polyfit(x, Y, 1). import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")    model = np.polyfit(data, 1) ? esto estaria bien?

Comment: El 1 es el grado. 1 = Lineal, 2 = Cuadrático, 3 = Cúbico, etc.

Comment: ¿Te interesa saber cómo hacerlo con scikitlearn?

Comment: Como le doy a la palomita jaja

Comment: @CarlosHernandez para saber qué es y cómo hacerlo mirate el enlace [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas), ahí tienes una imagen que aclara que es la "palomita" XD. Y por favor, edita la pregunta para que cumpla con las normas del sitio como te comentaba arriba luisfer sobre el título y yo sobre la imagen, tu pregunta es buena pero tal como está podría terminar incluso cerrada, corrigiendo eso es posible que te reviertan el negativo o al menos recibas algunos positivos. Saludos.

Comment: Hola colegas, muchas gracias por las observaciones de a poco ire aprendiendo con ustedes.

Comment: Hola grupo tengo una inquietud mas. Tengo las siguientes lineas de codigo pero no logro entender que realizan los parametros () <br/>8. X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test= train_test_split(iris.data,iris.target,test_size=0.4,random_state=0)   18. y_pred=cross_val_predict(clf,iris.data,iris.target,cv=5)... 19. conf_mat=confusion_matrix(iris.target,y_pred) en los parametros que esta haciendo cada linea de codigo

Comment: Ponlo en una pregunta nueva

Answer (score 0):

Para leer un csv desde python lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
```

con esto ya tienes toda tu información como DataFrame de Pandas y puedes manipularlo como gustes.

Sobre el entrenamiento puedes ver algo similar [aqui](https://becominghuman.ai/linear-regression-in-python-with-pandas-scikit-learn-72574a2ec1a5?gi=ce215c1c1e92)

Comment: pero el dataset debe estar en la ruta donde tengo mi codigo de spider o no...porque ya use ese codigo pero me sale el error citado anteriormente

Comment: El dataset lo puedes "buscar" con las rutas, nada más cambiando por `pd.read_csv("C:/User/folder/file.csv")`

Comment: Okey gracias, me sentare a leer casi no eh podido comprender mucho pero hare el intento. Me sigue dando vueltas porque no me da igual resultado print con el resultado de excel(este me da correcto) , el profe ya me paso el resultado

Comment: Claro, una recomendación es que practiques e investigues mucho y dudes en preguntar